# Blurred in TikZ and 3D shadows

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, shadows

I want to produce a 3D object like the one in the picture using `TikZ`. I am able to make the first one, clipping some svg paths on the object. But how can I blur it?

[image]

Comment: HI!  Could you share the code that you have already?  It might be easier to have an idea for the blurred part of your project.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you want to ray-trace. Typically I use povray(*) for that propose but a tiks solution would be interesting.

(*) http://www.povray.org/